# What is the advantage of using Random Access File instead of FIle Writer and FileReader?

Tags: java, file-io

I understood the classes `FileWriter` and `File Reader`.

I want to know about the class `RandomAccessFile` compared to `FileWriter` and `FileReader`.

Comment: Have you looked it up in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)? It's a file object that supports reading and writing at arbitrary byte locations within the file, instead of only going sequentially. From the doc: "A random access file behaves like a large array of bytes stored in the file system. There is a kind of cursor, or index into the implied array, called the file pointer; input operations read bytes starting at the file pointer and advance the file pointer past the bytes read."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RandomAccessFile is designed for random access of *binary* data. i.e. you can access anywhere in the file by index.

FileReader and FileWriter are for reading and writing *text*, not binary, sequentially.